# How to enable edge extension using powershell script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge-extension

Post installation  of an application it creates a edge extension but by default it is turned off.
Does anyone have solution to enable it using powershell script?

I'm new to powershell to not sure how to and where to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, test without Powershell.

Add the ID under HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallForcelist

Check via edge://extensions

Only manage extensions via either HKCU or HKLM.

More information on [Information about extensions](https://www.vroom.cc/joomla/howto/ivanti-workspace-control/implementing-chrome-and-edge-chromium-extensions-via-group-policy-and-ivanti-workspace-control).

When this works, you can write the PowerShell code to modify the registry accordingly.

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot